# Index was outside the bounds of the array on a Dictionary

Tags: c#, file, dictionary

I have an app that loads a file that's formatted like `key:value` and then adds it to a `Dictionary`. This works well with small files, but when I try to load a file that has like 65,000 lines, it won't work and throws `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` on the `Dictionary.TryAdd()`.

I compile my app for 64-bit architectures and I also set the `<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects enabled="true" />` in the `app.config`.

```
private void LoadFile()
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> Dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

    OpenFileDialog dlgFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlgFile.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    dlgFile.FilterIndex = 1;

    if (dlgFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(dlgFile.FileName))
        {
            // Index was outside the bounds of the array.
            Dict.TryAdd(line.Split(':')[0], line.Split(':')[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the array indexing. Are you sure that all "lines" are in the required format, aka can be split by ':'?

Comment: @Daniel Leszen Yes, they are

Comment: I'd suggest you check again.  When the exception is thrown, mouse-over `line` to see what the value is that fails. The likelihood is it doesn't contain `:` - if you're sure they all do, then it's sometimes the last (empty) line.

Comment: @J.Ivanovic The generic `Dictionary` class doesn't have a `TryAdd()` method - which class are you using?

Comment: How could I skip empty lines?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen per the code, `ConcurrentDictionary`

Comment: It's a concurrentdictionary. And I also cannot think of any other reason than array indexing

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I am using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly because one of your lines doesn't contain `:`, so the indexing into the resulting split `string` array will fail as there aren't 2 parts to it.

You could skip lines that don't have two parts like so:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(dlgFile.FileName))
{
    var parts = line.Split(':');

    if (parts.Length == 2)
    {
         var key = parts[0];
         var value = parts[1];
         Dict.TryAdd(key, value);
    }
    else
    {
         // log that line was ignored
    }
}
```

As an aside, there is no need to use `ConcurrentDictionary` unless you have concurrent access.  There may be elsewhere in your application, but there is none in the code you've shown.

Comment: As I commented in the other answer, I now got another problem.
`The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xb40a9278 to COM context 0xb40a93a0 for 60 seconds. `

Comment: Hit continue and keep waiting.  It's likely this is just taking a long time, which may be an argument for not doing this on the UI thread.

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` maybe?

Comment: @J.Ivanovic that's one option, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try modifying the foreach body to the following code segment:

```
        var parts = line.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (parts.Length > 1)
        {
            Dict.TryAdd(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }
        else
        {
            // ERROR logging
        }
```

Removing empty entries is not neccesary, however it makes sure you would not add empty keys or values to the dictionary. I would also suggest to make sure, the dictionary does not contain the same key.

Comment: This solved my problem but lead to another.
`The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xb40a9278 to COM context 0xb40a93a0 for 60 seconds. `